# Colocar relógio em uma <TD>

Tags: html, inserir

Estou apanhando para colocar um relógio dentro de uma tag

Tenho esse código da função do relógio que peguei na internet

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

Nesse exemplo me mostra para inserir o relógio dessa forma

```
<body onload="startTime()">
    <p id="demo"></p>
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Mas quero colocar no trecho do código onde está escrito "Tempo de espera"
pois se trata do tempo de espera do cliente para o retorno da ligação.

```
<td>0001</td>
        <td>11:05</td>
        <td>Suporte</td>
        <td>Luciana</td>
        <td>5292 - J ALVES CONTABIL</td>
        <td>Norma</td>
        <td>Tempo de espera</td>
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Bem-vindo Fabio Ozuna, já fez um tour pelo site?   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer uso de `Table cells Collection`

> Inserindo o relógio na 6ª célula (`<td>`) da 1ª linha (`<tr>`)
>
> `rows[0].cells; x[6]`

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);

 var x = document.getElementById("qqId").rows[0].cells;
  x[6].innerHTML =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

startTime();
```

```html
<table border="1" id="qqId">
<tr>
<td>0001</td>
<td>11:05</td>
<td>Suporte</td>
<td>Luciana</td>
<td>5292 - J ALVES CONTABIL</td>
<td>Norma</td>
<td>Tempo de espera</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

> Inserindo o relógio na 5ª célula (`<td>`) da 2ª linha (`<tr>`)

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);

 var x = document.getElementById("qqId").rows[1].cells;
  x[5].innerHTML =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

startTime();
```

```html
<table border="1" id="qqId">
<tr>
<td>0001</td>
<td>11:05</td>
<td>Suporte</td>
<td>Luciana</td>
<td>5292 - J ALVES CONTABIL</td>
<td>Norma</td>
<td>Tempo de espera</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0002</td>
<td>11:12</td>
<td>Adm</td>
<td>Cadu</td>
<td>5298 - CADU ADMINISTRAÇÃO</td>
<td>Norma</td>
<td>Tempo de espera</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image: BROWSER SUPORTE]

Answer (score 0):

É só você utilizar alguma tag com o ID igual ao passado no `document.getElementById()`. Recomendo que use uma tag que não altere visualmente a estrutura do HTML, ex: `<div>`, `<span>`, etc...

Nesse exemplo que vc citou, basta fazer assim:

```html
<td>Tempo de espera: <div id="txt"></div> </td>
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente para o que precisava.